# Formatting code fragments extracted from file with minted

Tags: verbatim, expansion, minted, catchfile

I would like to use the [`catchfilebetweentags`](http://ctan.org/pkg/catchfilebetweentags) package to grab code snippets from a source file and use [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) to highlight them.

Imagine I have the following in `program.scala`:

```
//<a
def someFunctionA = {
  // some code
}
//a>

def aFunctionIDontCareAbout = {
  // irrelevant stuff
}

//<b
def someFunctionB = {
  // important code!
}
//b>
```

and the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

% Nicely formatted snippet:
\begin{minted}{scala}
  def someNicelyHighlightedFunction = {
    // not from the file
  }
\end{minted}

% Expanding, but unformatted snippet:
\CatchFileBetweenDelims{\a}{program.scala}{<a}{//a>}
\a

% Non-expanding snippet inside minted environment:
\CatchFileBetweenDelims{\b}{program.scala}{<b}{//b>}
\begin{minted}{scala}
  \b
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can get `\b` to expand inside the `verbatim` environment used by `minted`?

(I am not committed to `catchfilebetweentags` or to `minted` in particular, but I do need [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) highlighting on extracted code fragments.)

Comment: See https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/76.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`catchfilebetweentags` will get tricky with catcodes.  Since you already have `fancyvrb` loaded, already have `\write18` enabled (shell escape), and have Python (to use Pygments), I would suggest a pure Python solution.  This is designed for tags that don't need to be escaped  by either LaTeX or Python, though it could be adapted.

The basic idea is to use `fancyvrb`'s `VerbatimOut` to create a Python script that will read your code and save the relevant portion in a temporary file.  This script is executed automatically via `\write18`. Then the temporary file is read in via `minted`'s `\inputminted`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{minted_delim.py}
import sys
codefile = sys.argv[1]
delim1 = sys.argv[2]
delim2 = sys.argv[3]
f = open(codefile)
code = f.read()
f.close()
f = open(codefile + '.snippet', 'w')
try:
    f.write(code.split(delim1, 1)[1].split(delim2, 1)[0])
except:
    f.write('MINTED DELIM ERROR')
f.close()
\end{VerbatimOut}

\newcommand{\inputmintedbetweendelims}[5][]{%
  \immediate\write18{python minted_delim.py "#3" "#4" "#5"}%
  \inputminted[#1]{#2}{#3.snippet}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{scala}
  def someNicelyHighlightedFunction = {
    // not from the file
  }
\end{minted}

\inputmintedbetweendelims{scala}{program.scala}{<b}{//b>}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Question, though: what's the fifth argument to `\inputmintedbetweendelims` for? `#5` is passed to the python script, but the latter doesn't seem to use `sys.argv[4]` anywhere... ?

Comment: @NicolasPayette The script receives the name of the code file (`#3`), the opening delim (`#4`), and the closing delim (`#5`).  `sys.argv[0]` is the script name, so `#3` becomes `sys.argv[1]`, `#4` becomes `sys.argv[2]`, and `#5` becomes `sys.argv[3]`.

Comment: Oh, right, I see now. What confused me is the fact that it's the _first_ arg of a LaTeX command that can be optional (`#1`, which in this case becomes the options arg to `\inputminted`). I also was not aware that `sys.argv[0]` is passed as the script name in Python. Anyway, thanks for the clarification!